# dfrac not centered in multirow

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I produce the following table:

[image]

Why the frac in the circle is not in the center, but very near to third line? How to fix this?

The code follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=1.91cm,right=1.91cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.4em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
Πηγή & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Βαθμοί \\ ελευθερίας \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Άθροισμα \\ τετραγώνων \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Μέσο άθροισμα \\ τετραγώνων \end{tabular}}   & $F_c$ \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Θεραπεία \\ \textlatin{(Between groups)} \end{tabular}} & $k-1$ & $SSTR$ & $\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$\dfrac{\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}}{\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}}$}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Σφάλματα \\ \textlatin{(Within groups)} \end{tabular}} & $n-k$ & $SSE$ & $\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}$ & \\ \midrule
Σύνολο & $n-1$ & $TSS$ & & \\ \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

A trick is to use

```
\multirow{2}{*}{$\dfrac{\frac{SSTR}{k-1}}{\frac{SSE}{n-k}}$}
```

rather than

```
\multirow{2}{*}{$\dfrac{\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}}{\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}}$}
```

But this is not a complete solution. The fraction is still not in the center of the cell.

The result follows.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated comment: all your `\multicolumn` are redundant; you can safely eliminate them.

Comment: You can use the optional argument of `\multirow` to raise its contents.

Comment: @Bernard this is true, but then the space between the second and the third line (especially in the first column) is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could come up with is

```
\multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{$\genfrac{}{}{0.8}0{\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}}{\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}}$}
```

I use `\multirow{4}` because it covers in fact 4 lines. I did some debugging and it seems the outer `\dfrac` causes the numerator en denominator to have different heights, i.e. the fraction line is not in the vertical center of the complete formula. I have compensated with the `[1.5ex]` vmove parameter. The 1.5ex is found bt trial and error. I have checked that this doesn't affect the spacing of the rest of the table.
I also removed the useless `\multirow{1}{c}`'s.
You might also replace the outer `\dfrac` with a `\genfrac` to get a more prominent division line.
This together gives the following table.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=1.91cm,right=1.91cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.4em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
Πηγή & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Βαθμοί \\ ελευθερίας \end{tabular} & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Άθροισμα \\ τετραγώνων \end{tabular}} & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Μέσο άθροισμα \\ τετραγώνων \end{tabular}}   & $F_c$ \\ \midrule
{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Θεραπεία \\ \textlatin{(Between groups)} \end{tabular}} & $k-1$ & $SSTR$ & $\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}$ & \multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{$\dfrac{\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}}{\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}}$}\\

{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Σφάλματα \\ \textlatin{(Within groups)} \end{tabular}} & $n-k$ & $SSE$ & $\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}$ & \\ \midrule
Σύνολο & $n-1$ & $TSS$ & & \\ \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's perfect. Actually I tried with 4 because of the 4 lines, but I could not achieve the desired output because I did not use [1.5ex].

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, you merge cells (both vertically and horizontally) with the command `\Block`. The content is put mathematically at the center with PGF/Tikz. So, you provide the number of logical rows, and not the number of physical lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=1.91cm,right=1.91cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.4em}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
Πηγή 
& \Block{}{Βαθμοί \\ ελευθερίας} & 
\Block{}{Άθροισμα \\ τετραγώνων} &
\Block{}{Μέσο άθροισμα \\ τετραγώνων} 
& $F_c$ \\ \midrule
\Block{}{Θεραπεία \\ \textlatin{(Between groups)}}
& $k-1$ & $SSTR$ & $\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}$ 
& \Block{2-1}{$\dfrac{\dfrac{SSTR}{k-1}}{\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}}$}\\
\Block{}{Σφάλματα \\ \textlatin{(Within groups)}}
& $n-k$ & $SSE$ & $\dfrac{SSE}{n-k}$ & \\ \midrule
Σύνολο & $n-1$ & $TSS$ & & \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]